Robot vacuum cleaners and filtering performance
I'm new to this community, here is my first post. Sorry if I bring a more general topic (not about robotics itself). I am not an engineer, developer, etc., I write just as an 'average consumer'.
I have had a chronic allergy to dust since I was a child. Last year I bought a water filter vacuum cleaner (not a robot) which I think is the most efficent device to trap small particles. I mainly use it to vacuum mattresses and pillows.
Now I am considering buying a robot vacuum cleaner but after doing some online search I find controversy as if they have true HEPA filters, but generically called high efficiency filters instead, of which I haven't found their filtering performance.
I have read the true HEPA has thicker material and need more powerful motors.
My questions are:

How different are generic so-called high efficiency filters from true HEPA filters?
I, being allergic, should be concerned about tiny particles getting expelled back to ambient when the filters are not HEPA?


question #2 cannot possibly have a no answer, therefore the question is not very useful ... all three questions are not about robotics

Thanks @jsotola for your feedback. I agree, I was struggling about where to place my question. I have now  learned (by asking at META community) that I should go with a more medical community. Anyway, I edited my question a bit in a try to make it a bit clearer and more direct. To summ up, it is just: are filters of vacuum clearner robots as good as HEPA for allergic people? If eventually the question is off-topic in this community, no problem removing it.

question #1 is simply not related to robotics at all ... question #2 is entirely your choice and also not related to robotics in any way, logically it can never have a no answer. .... the question about the filter may be on topic at the engineering site, but I do not know for certain
